# Localization not working after app restart

Tags: android, localization

I'm including localization to translate my app intro three different languages, after setting up the translated strings of each language, I go to preference settings and I check a checkbox and and the translation works fine, the problem is that when I restart the app , localization even though I have saved the chosen language in sharedpreference and retreiving it in mainactivity

*This is how I'm setting the languages

```
var sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", 
           Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 var editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

 spanishCheckBox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(object : Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener{
                override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference?, newValue: Any?): Boolean {
                    var isSpanishChecked = newValue as Boolean
                    if(isSpanishChecked){
                        var Lang = "es"
                        editor.putString("key",Lang)
                        editor.apply()
                        var local = Locale(Lang)
                        var configuration = Configuration()
                        configuration.locale = local
                        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,resources.displayMetrics)

                        englishCheckBox.isChecked = false
                        frenchCheckBox.isChecked = false

                        Intent(requireContext(),MainActivity::class.java).also {
                            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                            startActivity(it)
                        }
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
```

- This is how i m retreiving data in mainactivity

```
 fun LoadLanguageConfiguration(){
        var sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var langCode = sharedpreferences.getString("key","")
        var local = Locale(langCode)
        var configuration = Configuration()
        configuration.locale = local
        baseContext.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }
```

The translation only works when I set the language in the app, but when I restart the app, it goes back to default language which is English.

Comment: Did you mean that sharedpreference is deleting the value of "key" when the app restarting? or the value still same as before restarting but the language not changing.

Comment: upon checking using the debugger , the value is retreived normally but it is not being applied to localization , even when i set the value manually , the app language is not changed

Comment: Where do you call LoadLanguageConfiguration(), you should call it very early stage of your app startup.

Comment: I'm calling in in the oncreate , so  as soon as the app lauches , it should check that method

Comment: Would you try to call LoadLanguageConfiguration() at onStart function ?. 
As the android lifecycle onStart called after onRestart and after oncreate.

Comment: So, why don't you update the configuration changes as you did on setOnPreferenceChangeListener by adding this line at the end of the function resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,resources.displayMetrics)

Comment: I guess  the problem is that i was calling that method oncreate and it was the last  thing i called , so i put the method to be loaded first oncreate and it is working now , thank you guys for the help

Comment: There is just one thing to ask guys and it is about the same topic , i have an onboard intro in which i have some strings , but it is launched before the mainactivity , is there anyway to load the translation there ?

Comment: You have to override `attachBaseContext` in every Activiy. Inside this methode You have to set the current devive language or read it from You `SharedPreference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was not starting my language loading method at the start and before everything, so I put it as first method in my oncreate and everything works as supposed to.